# TestForBlock command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a custom crafting table using a dropper. I use this command to detect a shovel that is placed in the dropper:

```
testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper 0 {Items:[0:{id:minecraft:stone_shovel,Count:1b,Damage:0s,Slot:4b}]}
```

And it works, it detects the shovel in the middle as it is supposed to.
So the shovel is in the middle right now, and the comparator activates. If I keep the shovel there, and put another item into a different slot, the redstone comparator still activates. I want it to only activate when there is 1 item in the table.

My idea is to detect air for the other 8 slots, but it is not working, is `minecraft:air` invalid?
How do I make `/testforblock` detect air (blank slot) inside the container (dropper)?

Comment: First, if you're not using 1.9, you probably should be.  The fact that you have a comparator suggests that you're using 1.8, unless it's just to provide an indicator.  Second, it isn't air that's in those slots, they're just empty, nothing more.

Comment: I am not using a comparator to detect the contents of the dropper, I am using it as an output for the command block that detects the contents.

Comment: An empty block in minecraft is minecraft:air
now are you going to help me or just correct my statements?

Comment: Whoa, take it easy, I'm just trying to give some helpful advice and correct a misconception.  It's not hard to see why you had that misconception, but it's important for you to understand your misconception before you get a full answer.  You still seem to be holding onto that misconception, and it seems you misunderstood the first part of my previous comment.  You have to be patient, as you're not going to get an answer instantly (although you have a good one now).

Comment: Sorry about that, I was just looking for the answer for a long time. I signed up just to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

"air" is indeed not a valid inventory item. Slots without items will simply not exist whatsoever, so you cannot directly detect them through NBT.

What you'll need to do instead is use multiple `/testforblock` commands: one to detect the shovel and others to detect slots having any items in them. You'd only allow a signal to pass if the first succeeds while the others fail:

Must succeed:

```
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone_shovel",Count:1b,Damage:0s,Slot:4b}]}
```

Must all fail:

```
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:0b}]}
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:1b}]}
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:2b}]}
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:3b}]}
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:5b}]}
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:6b}]}
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:7b}]}
/testforblock 193 58 -314 minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:8b}]}
```

What you **cannot** do is combine all of the failure commands into one, because then it's looking for an item in *every* one of those slots rather than *any* one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was worried my map wouldn't be safe. :)